# Конфликт инструкции INSERT с ограничением FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql-server

```
    use knyazevprac10;
create table author10
([ID] varchar(100)primary key,
[Автор] varchar(100),
[Страна] varchar(100));

insert into author10 values 
('01', 'Пушкин А.А.', 'Россия'),
('02', 'Есенин Е.В.', 'Россия'),
('03', 'Бабич Г.Е.', 'Украина'),
('04', 'Крюгер Б.В.', 'Германия'),
('05', 'Барбё Г.И.', 'Франция'),
('06', 'Шелби Т.Н.', 'Америка'),
('07', 'Гулёв И.Б.', 'Беларусь'),
('08', 'Конфуций Х.Х.', 'Китай');

create table phrases10
([ID] varchar(100)primary key,
[Крылатая фраза] varchar(100),
[Темы] varchar(100),
[Ключевые слова] varchar(100));

insert into phrases10 values 
('01', 'Где родился - там и пригодился.', 'Родина', 'Родился'),
('02', 'Терпенье и труд всё перетрут.', 'Труд', 'Труд'),
('03', 'Поговори мне в рот.', 'Разговоры', 'Рот'),
('04', 'Не лезь в лес, там пень.', 'Природа', 'Лес'),
('05', 'Я всё.', 'Лирика', 'Всё'),
('06', 'Всё хорошо, что неплохо.', 'Добро', 'Хорошо'),
('07', 'Я съел DEADа.', 'Каннибализм', 'Дед'),
('08', 'Завести кота - воистину КОТОстрофа!.', 'Природа', 'Кот');

create table maintable10
([ID] varchar(100)primary key,
[Тип фразы] varchar(100),
[Автор] varchar(100) foreign key references author10(ID),
[Крылатая фраза] varchar(100) foreign key references phrases10(ID),
[Источник] varchar(100),
[Год] varchar(100));

insert into maintable10 values 
('01', 'Пословица', 'Пушкин А.А.', 'Где родился - там и пригодился.', 'Журнал "Космостарс"', '2003'),
('02', 'Пословица', 'Есениин Е.В.', 'Терпенье и труд всё перетрут.', 'КФ "Зелёная ложка"', '1996'),
('03', 'Поговорка', 'Бабич Г.Е.', 'Поговори мне в рот.', 'КФ "Франция в берлине"', '1894'),
('04', 'Поговорка', 'Крюгер Б.В.', 'Не лезь в лес, там пень.', 'Письмо маме', '1636'),
('05', 'Афоризм', 'Барбё Г.И.', 'Я всё.', 'Предсмертная записка', '1943'),
('06', 'Афоризм', 'Шелби Т.Н.', 'Всё хорошо, что неплохо.', 'Журнал "Всё лучшее детям"', '2001'),
('07', 'Каламбур', 'Гулёв И.Б.', 'Я съел DEADа.', 'Интервью у Дудя', '2015'),
('08', 'Каламбур', 'Конфуций Х.Х.', 'Завести кота - воистину КОТОстрофа!', 'КФ "Габардиновый пень"', '1987');

select * from maintable10;
select * from author10;
select * from phrases10;
```

[image: Вот такая ошибка]

Comment: foreign key references phrases10(ID) <- тут ошибка должно быть [Крылатая фраза] Вообще ссылу лучше на целочисленное поле делать - ключ

Comment: И пора бы уже разобраться, какой сервер баз данных Вы используете. MS SQL (официальное название - SQL Server) - это вот ни разу не MySQL. PS. Тег изменён.

Comment: пишет "В таблице phrases10, на которую имеются ссылки, отсутствуют первичные или потенциальные ключи, соответствуюшие списку ссылающихся столбцов во внешнем ключе "FK_maintable10_a6a470bb46e2c30760ac""

Comment: @Luck3r04 Вы в вопросе поправьте, то, что сделали. Как таблицы поменяли - уберите лишнее (сверху)

Comment: foreign key references author10(ID), <- это тоже не верно, должно быть [Автор], это исходя из Ваших данных